# <select SELECTED> IF Statement within a Loop

Tags: php, mysql, logic

Hope this question makes sense!
I have an edit page which has a

```
<option><select>
```

part The

```
<select>
```

options themselves are from a database, so they are in a loop to have values as IDs and friendly name in the display bit. See below.

```
// Start loop to display products
                    $i=0;
                    while ($i < $num2) {

                        $catid=mysql_result($result2,$i,"id");
                        $catname=mysql_result($result2,$i,"category");



                //Write each product
                echo '<option value="';
                echo "$catid";
                echo '"';
                if ('$catid'=='$f_cat_id')
                {
                    echo ' selected ';
                }
                echo $f_cat_id;
                echo '>';
                echo "$catname";
                echo '</option>';


                // Repeat loop until finished
                        $i++;
                    }
```

You can see that as this is an EDIT page i have the value that was previously selected in a variable called $f_cat_id. Now i want to default it to Select IF $f_cat_id matches the value in the loop.

It seems however that my variable which is set like this...

```
$f_cat_id=$row['product_category_id'];
```

Doesn't seem to be available to use in an IF statement whilst in the loop?

Sure this is an easy question! look forward to your help!
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `if ('$catid'=='$f_cat_id')` drop the quote marks with them you are compareing the strings not the values of the variables,.

Comment: '$catid'=='$f_cat_id' will never match for sure :)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: maybe its old code? please do not spam every mysql question with this generic comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ('$catid'=='$f_cat_id')
```

That's the cause of the issue. PHP variables aren't interpolated when they're in single quotes. The `if` condition will always evaluate to `FALSE` and the code inside the `if` block won't get executed.

To prove it, consider the following expression:

```
$catid = 1;
$f_cat_id = 1;
var_dump('$catid' == '$f_cat_id');
```

The [output](https://eval.in/53247) will be:

```
bool(false)
```

So, change your code to:

```
if ($catid == $f_cat_id) {
    # code ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this! This was correct. I don't have enough rating to 'vote up' after you confirm this was correct I actually release this wasn't my 'overall' issue and that it was I wasn't pulling data correctly from the Database, thus it wouldnt ever return true! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two strings:

```
'$catid'=='$f_cat_id'
```

[Single quotes don't interpolate variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (you should use double quotes for [variable interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)).

Anyway you don't need interpolation at all, since you can simply compare the two variables:

```
if ($catid == $f_cat_id)
{
    echo ' selected ';
}
```